# C#: Stop Git commit if NUnit test fails

Tags: c#, .net, git, nunit, githooks

I have a VS Solution the structure of which you can see here:

[Solution Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmfZX.png)

I'm using NUnit 3.2.0 to run my tests.

How can I stop commits to my local branch if the NUnit test fails and display a message on the Git bash?

I read something about pre-commit hooks. How do I implement that here?

I'm using the NUnit Console Runner to test my *UnitTests.dll* using the following command line argument:

```
nunit3-conosle.exe UnitTests.dll /wait
```

P.S. Please let me know in the comments if you require more information regarding this.

Comment: You shouldn't really be running unit tests on commit. See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260778/is-it-a-good-practice-to-run-unit-tests-in-version-control-hooks

Comment: @Steve If you read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/260862.

Comment: @Steve I agree as to why shouldn't run unit tests on commit, but I'm okay with the trade off.

Comment: I can see the point to both sides. Personally I wouldn't run on commit but would have a continuous build running on each *push* set to fail if a unit test fails. In my view commits should be quick and painless and there are circumstances you may want to commit broken code - to get a colleague to work on it for example. Ultimately it's up to you, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @Steve I understand what you're trying to say. But I've been asked to have a continuous build running on each *commit* set to fail if unit test fails. I would have used something like Jenkins to take care of things for me if it was up to me. But, thank you for the comments. :)

Comment: What exactly do you miss to do what you need? If you have read about pre-commit, you should know already that [Exiting with non-zero status from this script causes the git commit to abort](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

Comment: But in *distrubuted* vcs it is really not needed. What matters is that your branch passes all tests before merging to master. Intermediate commits do not need even compile.